# Delete element of array without null as result

Tags: javascript

How do I delete an item from an array without null as the result?

```
var a = [1,2,3];
delete a[1];
a;
result: [1,null,3];
desired result: [1,3];
```

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete` operator simply [removes a property from an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), so that property becomes null.  It won't *resize* your array automatically.

To do this, use the `Splice` method:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a = a.splice(1, 1); // Remove one element from array, starting at index 1
```

[More Info on JavaScript Splice Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)